# Displaying two things scaled differently - ratio?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, idioms, synonyms, idiom-requests

If got a picture that displays things. As thing A is alot bigger than thing B, I have downsized A. Not mentioning this size adjustment may confuse viewers and transport a wrong message. How can I tell the viewer with as little words as possible that the sizes of A and B are not comparable without adjusting the scale.

> A is displayed with smaller ratio

Is this okay, or should I use `in` as a preposition? Is there a best practise way of saying this?

Answer (score 3):

"Not to scale" is probably the standard disclaimer.

Comment: They are both "to scale", only different scales!

Comment: Well, the question mentions one picture with two "things", so with the text applied to the picture as a whole I think it would be pretty clear. Otherwise "shown to different scales" or similar.